# Manage display of geofield with wkt input widget

Tags: location

I am stuck on something that seemed very simple and need your help.
I have an input form where there is a geofield input field of type WKT. So the user gives the WKT of a point. When the node is viewed I would like the WKT that the user previously gave to be displayed on a map. On the manage display tab all the other options seem to work (WKT, KML, description etc), except from the map option like leaflet, openlayers and geofield maps. There is empty space where the map was supposed to be.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: hi Mat, did u already check for any errors in the installation of your (leaflet) map? What is the format of the wkt that you are filling in? Are there maybe any errors there? Could u provide more information about the points that the users have to fill in? I was stuck with the same things in the beginning. I got it working with geocode the map form another field. For that field i used address field. More user friendly in my case because the user can fill in their address instead of wkt.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- make sure that you edit the right format when you filled in the wkt.
- check for any errors in the installation of the map.

I had the same problems in the beginning with mapping too. I had an error in the installation of my leaflet map. In the end I solved it with a new installation and I geocoded the geofield from my address field.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77420)

Comment: I wanted to try to help by asking if the op already checked those things. I had the same problems in the beginning with mapping too. I had an error in the installation of my leaflet map. In the end i solved it with a new installation and i geocoded the geofield from my address field.

Comment: but if you need more information add a comment, this is not a answer

Comment: I am sorry.. I tried that but I am not allowed to post new comments yet. My intentions weren't bad. Only wanted to help the op. If i can add a comment next time I will do that or otherwise don't ask my questions in the answer section.

Comment: don't worry, try again, you need 50rep to make a comment ;-)

Comment: Thnx.. I did:-). I will delete my answer.

Comment: @Lucy : please check my edits of your answer, in which I mostly only integrated your comment, and transformed "questions" to "suggestions". With that I think it's OK to not delete it, but of course: up to you ... Just trying to help, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I suppose it was a bug. The content type had two maps with location. When the first was empty then the second didn't show up and caused the empty space. When I removed the first map everything worked fine. But now I am stuck to this if anyone could help...
[Hide grey leaflet map if empty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198796/hide-grey-leaflet-map-if-empty)