# Hide grey leaflet map if empty

Tags: javascript

I have a content type where the user gives a location, this is not a mandatory field. When the user don't provide location the node shows a grey map. Is there a way to remove the grey map from showing up? I want it to be hidden if empty. Could anyone provide some help here?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I am facing the same situation and would like to hide the map when empty.